# Stored Procedure: only commit when successful

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, commit

I would like to build a stored procedure that:
1. truncates Table A
2. truncates Table B
3. inserts (lots) of rows in table A
4. inserts (lots) of rows in table B

The stored procedure should only commit the statements after step 4 so that the tables are not locked and experience no down time.
If an error occurs (for instance in step 4) all changes must be rolled back. I tried writing it myself but it committed after each statement.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE upall as

BEGIN
  execute immediate 'truncate table MAIN.SET';
  insert into MAIN.SET select * from MAIN.SET_STAG;

  execute immediate 'truncate table MAIN.TYPE';
  insert into MAIN.TYPE select * from MAIN.TYPE_STAG;

  COMMIT; 
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE; 
END;
```

Comment: TRUNCATE does an implicit commit, and cannot be rolled back in most cases ( flashback ).

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle, TRUNCATE TABLE is a DDL statement that cannot be used in a transaction (or, more accurately, cannot be rolled back).If there is a transaction in progress when the statement is executed, the transaction is committed and then the TRUNCATE is executed and cannot be undone.

Try DELETE FROM YourTable and finally update stats of your table (since DELETE will outdate it)

It will looks like :

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE upall as

BEGIN
    delete from MAIN.SET;
    insert into MAIN.SET select * from MAIN.SET_STAG;

    delete from MAIN.TYPE;
    insert into MAIN.TYPE select * from MAIN.TYPE_STAG;

    COMMIT; 

    EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('MAIN', 'SET');
    EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('MAIN', 'TYPE');

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE; 
END;
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. So what if I do this: `create or replace PROCEDURE upall as

BEGIN
  delete from MAIN.SET;
  insert into MAIN.SET select * from MAIN.SET_STAG;

  delete from MAIN.TYPE;
  insert into MAIN.TYPE select * from MAIN.TYPE_STAG;

  COMMIT; 
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE; 
END;`